# Does Bootstrap align two content like simple grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have been working on this for about a week. I aligned two classes within two columns using bootstrap, and made another separate class below the content. when I preview the web page, the separate class is being aligned with the two classes, instead of the seperate class being below the 2 column grid. How can the separate class be placed under a two column bootstrap grid? Below is an image of the result, as well as the code used. Thanks

```
   <div class="prod_section">
   <div class="border col-md-6">
      <img src="help.jpg" class="word" alt="h">
      <h2 class="header">SHIRT</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="border col-md-6 ">
      <img src="img/help_two.jpg" alt="" class="word">
      <h2 class="header"> URBAN SHIRT</h2>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="seperate">Is BOOTSTRAP suppose to appear like this?</div>



.prod_section{
    margin:auto;
    width:1300px;
    margin-top:600px;
    margin-bottom: 600px;
}

.word{
    max-width:90%;
    /*box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #bababa;*/
}

h2{
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-weight:700;
}
.header{
    padding-top:20px;
}
body{
    background:white;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put those `col-md-6` into `.row` div like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap, you need to start your divs off like so

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="one"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="word" alt="h">PIC A</div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="two"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="" class="word">Pic B</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-6 seperate"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">Is BOOTSTRAP suppose to appear like this? Div 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To get the most out of bootstraps grid system you need to wrap everything in a `<div class="container">` then `<div class="row">` row is responsible for making sure everything within it is aligned in the same "row" as long as the grids do not go over 12 columns. Finally you need to give each div a size, how many columns they will take up. 1 - 12 columns. Here we have 3 divs taking up 6 columns each `<div class="column-md-6">`. The first two `<div>`s are inside there own row and taking up 12 columns in total while for the finaly `<div>` we go outside of the row, but still inside of the `<div class="container">` div and create a new row, `<div class="row">`. Then its just a matter of creating your divs and giving them column width. This is NOT a complete rundown of bootstrap what so ever but it is a simple overview of how the grid system works. Go ahead and read up a little more on bootstrap from the site, bootstrap 4 is not out yet but the alpha version is safe to use, I personally have not run into any problems so far.
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/